# Redirect focus on EditText when sibling is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, focus

I want my EditText to gain focus when its sibling or parent is touched (clicked).

Is it possible to do so via XML or programmatically?

I have already tried to set the following attributes on the container (LinearLayout) and the sibling (AppCompatTextView)

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible,

you need to set onClickListner on the sibling view
the in that onClickListner call  `editText.requestFocus();`
like below

```
siblingView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

  editText.requestFocus();        

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.
I was wondering though, since i have to do it for several items, is it possible to do IT via XML?

Comment: what is your sibling view?

Comment: The TextView is the EditText's sibling

Answer (score 1):

On click of the sibling view, you can simply request focus on your edittext by calling - `editText.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 0):

To do it using XML, you can add the following in your code

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp">

        <requestFocus/>

    </EditText>
```